# Count every button click and display it on input type number

Tags: javascript

I have a function where my button adds a table row every time you click it.
My target is, how can I display the value of my button click in my input type="number"? The value of my input type should be starting at "1", and every time when the button is clicked, increment by 1. Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" id="clickCount" onClick="clickMe" value="click me"></button>
 <input type="number" id="showMe" value="1"> // the value of my button clicks should be displayed here
```

Comment: HTML values are Strings. Cast like `(+Element.value)`, before adding.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```js
document.getElementById("clickCount").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("showMe").value++;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="showMe" value="1">
<button type="button" id="clickCount">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="clickCount" value="0"/>
   <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
</form>

function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('clickCount').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('clickCount').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the current value of the element on each click. I will also suggest you to avoid inline event handler.

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById('clickCount').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('showMe').value++;
});

//similarly you can decrease
document.getElementById('decrease').addEventListener('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('showMe').value--;
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="clickCount" value="click me">+</button>
<input type="number" id="showMe" value="1">
<button type="button" id="decrease" value="click me">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

Click Me

```
  const addNumber = document.getElementById("clickCount");
  const showNum = document.getElementById("showMe");
  addNumber.onclick = () => {
    showNum.value++;
  };
```